# Cisco Switch (Cayalyst 2960-X): How to add a rule to the access list that filters out l2tp packet when a specific MAC address appears in it?

Tags: cisco, ipv4, cisco-catalyst, ip, cisco-commands

I am using a Cayalyst 2960-X series Cisco Switch, Whose 2 SFPs are connecting between 2 hosts (A,B).

A,B are connected to the switch's 1,2 ports respectively.
The host communicates using an l2tp based protocol. As you know [l2tp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol) is a link layer protocol.

As part of the l2tp traffic sourced at host A whose destination is B, there are few packets I want to deny from getting to port 2 / Host B.

The packets that I want to drop have a source MAC address of `88:77:66:55:44:33` in their Ethernet 2 metadata, which is part of the whole l2tp packet (see the byte layout bellow).

I would like to set a rule or an access list that drops the l2tp packet by inspecting its Ethernet 2 attribute and in case the specific `88:77:66:55:44:33` MAC address appears in the SA.

I am familiar with the `mac access-list` command but every manual I had seen explicitly says that ACLs filter only `non-IP protocols`. In spite of that I tried to use `mac access-list` and indeed it didn't help.

Moreover, I found the [Catalyst 2960-X Switch Security Configuration Guide, Cisco IOS
Release 15.0(2)EX](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960x/software/15-0_2_EX/security/configuration_guide/b_sec_152ex_2960-x_cg.pdf), and under the `Restrictions for Configuring Network Security with ACLs` section it says:

> You cannot apply named MAC extended ACLs to Layer 3 interfaces.

**Isn't it feasible to filter ip protocols by drill down and inspecting their Ethernet 2 Mac addresses data?**

---

By sniffing the traffic between the 2 hosts, I can tell the packets has the following byte layout (As I see on Wireshark):

```
 0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |        Ethernet 2 (14 Bytes)     |       IP(20 Bytes)         |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   | IP  |L2TP 4B|HDLC 4B| Data                                    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Comment: To be clear, the l2tp is configured between hosts A & B, not on the 2960-X itself (I don't recall the platform having that capability, but could be wrong)? Second, the source MAC address you reference is from the frame header of the traffic going to the switch, not part of the data encapsulated in the tunnel? Finally, what do you mean by "prevent from getting to port 2"? Is this sourced from port 1 and you want to drop it when received on that interface or sourced from elsewhere on the network and you want to drop it before it leaves port 2 destined to host B?

Comment: @YLearn, l2tp is between host A and B only. The SA is from the frame header and not encapsulated in some awkward way. It is sourced at host A (which is connected to port 1) and I want to filter such a packet from arriving to host B.

Comment: @YLearn basically I am using the switch in order to deny/permit specific data patterns that arrives at port 1.

Comment: Are you saying you want to filter by the inside mac-address inside an L2TP tunnel?  There is no possible way a 2960 (or other non-L7-aware device) will be able to accomplish this.

Comment: @cpt_fink I want to filter by the SA in the Ethernet 2 sector in the packet's frame

Comment: Is the mac-address you want to filter by encapsulated in the L2TP tunnel or not?

Comment: @cpt_fink, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a L2 firewall that can match an offset for the inner MAC, assuming MAC isn't encrypted.

Comment: @generalnetworkerror the traffic isn't encrypted

Comment: @0x90 Did you try my ACL posted as an answer below?  It may be that it will only work on 'out', not 'in'.

Comment: @RonRoyston, I can't see how your edited answer is different from the second one

Comment: Mine 8 lines, his 5 lines.  Just paste it in and try?...  Can't hurt.

Comment: Pasting an ACL "can't hurt"?

Comment: Apparently mac access-list will only work when the switch is in LAN mode.
Here is a webpage discussing it: [mac access-list](http://aconaway.com/2008/10/27/using-mac-access-lists/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion about this topic for you. Let's begin by clearing up a few details.

> I am familiar with the mac access-list command but every manual I had seen explicitly says that ACLs filter only non-IP protocols.

If you think about this a bit, it makes sense. An IP packet doesn't contain a MAC addresses, so this would be difficult.  However, IP traffic is encapsulated in a L2 protocol, typically Ethernet which does utilize MAC addresses.

> You cannot apply named MAC extended ACLs to Layer 3 interfaces.

Again, this is natural. Since MAC ACLs function on L2, they wouldn't really need/want them on a L3 interface anyway.

However, by default interfaces on a 2960-X are layer 2 interfaces, so you can apply a MAC access-list to them.

So, this series of commands should provide the result you want (using the first SFP port on a WS-C2960X-48FPS-L so adjust as necessary):

```
! Create the ACL
mac access-list extended TestACL
deny host 8877.6655.4433 any
permit any any

! Now apply to the interface
interface Gi1/0/49
mac access-group TestACL in
```

---

**Edit based on comments**: if you want to rule out the source port being incorrect, you can use the following with the above ACL to block all traffic from that MAC going out the second SFP port:

```
! Now apply to the interface
interface Gi1/0/50
mac access-group TestACL out
```

If that doesn't work, then the MAC address has to be incorrect and you need to provide more information.

The ACL will work no matter if the MAC address table is updated dynamically or if you add a static entry. However, if the dynamic entry for this MAC is flapping between different ports, that could explain why the ACL didn't work as intended.  Additionally, without additional features configured, the static entry will not have an effect on traffic arriving on a port, only on the destination port used for the traffic.

And finally, the packet being highlighted in red by Wireshark doesn't tell me much. Different versions of Wireshark have used different coloring rules, the default rules typically include a number of matches that get colored red, and many of us use our own custom rules. You would need to provide more detail or the actual capture for us to know what exactly that means.

Comment: On my 2960-X's, `mac access-list` is not an available command, so the difference is one is a valid command and the other isn't.

Comment: I did try the `mac access-list extended` you had suggested. Unfortunately, It doesn't work for me and the packets aren't get filtered out.

Comment: This works fine on my 2960-X when I tested. Perhaps you could include an actual capture of the packets in question? At this point I would have to say either they aren't arriving on the port you believe they are or the MAC you provided isn't accurate.

Comment: The byte layout isn't sufficient? I am 100% sure it is correct.

Comment: If the information you provided was correct, the above would work. My testing showed this dropped all traffic with the source address (TCP, UDP, ICMP, etc). If it isn't working for you, something is off. The two most likely causes for this I provided in my last comment.

Comment: Yes I know. That what I tried on the first place. The Mac is for sure correct too, the only weird thing about this packet is that wireshark red highlights it

Comment: I think ACL can't handle traffic from a port that changes its SA on the fly. it seems that using `mac address-table static` might do the work.

Comment: @0x90, I have updated my answer based on the information provided in your comments.  You may want to update the question to include the additional details you have provided in comments.

Comment: From the 2960-X guide: Port ACLs can only be applied to Layer 2 interfaces in the inbound direction. If your static MAC address assignment is working then it would appear to be the destination. Flip your source and destination statements in the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

I used `mac address-table static` in order to drop the packets with the `8877.6655.4433` MAC address.

Apparently working with static address table entries is more robust way of doing such things.

Comment: So, that command statically configures a mapping of a MAC address to a particular interface / port.  How does that prevent or drop frames from getting to port 2?   ...are you sending them to a black hole, e.g. port 3, by statically mapping 8877... to port 3?

Comment: yes ....  Assuming not all the ports are in use

Comment: I have to agree with Ron, this sounds like a poor workaround and not an ideal solution. Also, based on this, while you keep claiming that this MAC address is the SA, this would only work if it were the DA as the MAC address table is only concerned with the DA and not the SA for forwarding decisions (obviously it uses the SA for learning).

Comment: This is a bandaid and less than ideal.  Can you run additional commands on your switch to see where these frames are flowing to?  I'm inclined to believe [YLearn's comment](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/cisco-switch-cayalyst-2960-x-how-to-add-an-access-list-to-filter-an-ip-based-p#comment29514_19499) is more than likely the case you're facing.

Answer (score -2):

```
Switch# configure terminal
Switch(config)# mac access-list extended maclist1
Switch(config-ext-macl)# deny 8877.6655.4433 any
Switch(config-ext-macl)# deny any 8877.6655.4433
Switch(config-ext-macl)# permit any any
Switch(config-ext-macl)# end
Switch(config)# interface gigabitethernet1/0/1
Switch(config-if)# mac access-group mac1 out
Switch(config)# interface gigabitethernet1/0/2
Switch(config-if)# mac access-group mac1 out
Switch(config-if)# end
```